# How to retrieve data from below data with SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have one table `TestTable` with this sample data:

```
|ID   | Desc    | CommentDate                 | qty |  light
+-----+---------+-----------------------------+-----+--------
| A11 | EYE     | 2019-01-01 01:00:00.000     | 10  |   20
| A11 | WOMEN   | 2019-01-01 05:00:00.000     | 15  |   13
| A11 | SUG     | 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000     | 10  |   20
| B11 | WOMEN   | 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000     | 20  |   30
```

I had tried to retrieve data from above `TestTable`. I did not get actual result return data, yet.

If `ID` have multiple comment date, take all from group top date of ID.
Expected result should be below.

```
|ID   | Desc    | CommentDate                 | qty |  light
+-----+---------+-----------------------------+-----+--------
| A11 | EYE     | 2019-01-01 01:00:00.000     | 10  |   20
| A11 | WOMEN   | 2019-01-01 05:00:00.000     | 15  |   13
| B11 | WOMEN   | 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000     | 20  |   30
```

Comment: What database is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

Live test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33fd9aea8a01dcd1aca98416bcacadfd

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Id
            order by convert(date, CommentDate)
        ) RN,
        *
    FROM
        tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Output:

```
RN  ID  Desc    CommentDate         qty light
1   A11 EYE     01/01/2019 01:00:00 10  20
1   A11 WOMEN   01/01/2019 05:00:00 15  13
1   B11 WOMEN   02/01/2019 00:00:00 20  30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below SQL query to get result set.

```
 ;WITH CTE AS( SELECT    [Id] ,[Desc] ,[CommentDate] ,[Qty],[Light]  ,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Desc] ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, [CommentDate]) ASC) RN  FROM TestTable )
 SELECT * FROM CTE   WHERE RN =1
```

Here `ORDER BY [CommentDate] ASC` will sort result by ASC order of `CommentDate` If you want last date record then use  `ORDER BY [CommentDate] DESC`

Comment: Thanks your answer, but there is not solve yet. There is Two type of ID , Need to take every top date of  ID . Should return for A11 =>  A11, EYE,2019-01-01 and A11 WOMEN,2019-01-01  and  B11,Women,2019-01-02    .Should not return for A11 ,SUG ,2019-01-02.